# Alternative ways to take particle tracks photographs in a cloud chamber

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, particle-physics, experimental-technique, particle-detectors

I know that the most common type of particle tracks photography is in photographic plates, but i'm using a cloud chamber and I would like to know if there are alternative ways to take photographs of the particle tracks in a cloud chamber.

Comment: "Photographic plates" is an implementation detail that is rather out of date. Use a digital camera.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the tracks using any half-decent digital video or photographic camera. Just look at this video on Youtube, and many more like it, for a demonstration:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xky3f1aSkB8

Answer (score 0):

I am making very good quality movies using my tablet Asus ZenPad. For example step by step instructions how to operate my cloud chamber. Also using laser pointer showing the respective parts of the chamber accordingly. Good luck.